# How to add multiple references of model in java REST API of return type arrayList?

Tags: java, spring, rest, arraylist, postman

The code below throws me error **JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.application.userManagementSystem.Model.User` out of START_ARRAY token**

```
public List<User> addUsers(User user) {
    user.setId(userID);
    userID++;
    userList2.add(user);
    userList2.add(user);
    userList2.add(user);
    return userList2;}
```

This is my user2 list

```
private List userList2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is what I am trying at postman:

```
[
    {           
    "id":0,
    "firstName":"rts43",
    "lastName":"Kmwn",
    "userName":"user1@example.com",
    "password":"pass1",
    "active":true   
    },

    {           
    "id":0,
    "firstName":"rts44",
    "lastName":"Kmwnl",
    "userName":"user2@example.com",
    "password":"pass2",
    "active":false  
    }
]
```

Here's the code for controller class API:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public List<User> addUsers(@RequestBody User user){
    return userServiceImplementation.addUsers(user);
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi Niharika! Welcome to Stack Overflow!

It seems like you are posting a list of users, but you are accepting a User on the server side;

Could you please include the Spring Controller class in your question. That is most likely where your mistake is.

Comment: Hi @TomCools I do have a controller class.This method is from the service class.Let me add it for easy reference.

Comment: @PostMapping("/add")
    public List<User> addUsers(@RequestBody User user){
        return userServiceImplementation.addUsers(user);
    }

Comment: you are posting multiple Users. So it should be @RequestBody List<User> users

Comment: Thanks @TomCools yup I corrected my mistake and it works fine thank you :) .I just have 1 more question previously in my other add method I was updating the user id by accessing the setter method of my User model since it is a list now I don't know how to do it.

Comment: If i helped, could you please upvote my Answer? :-) Helps me a lot.
For your userid, you can let it be generated by the Database (which is usually the best to do). For that, I'd need to see the definition of your User class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting multiple Users.

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public List<User> addUsers(@RequestBody List<User> user){
    return userServiceImplementation.addUsers(user);
}
```